# Troubles making this async/Await logic work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following function in my React app.js

```js
login = (email, password) => {
  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:3003/login",
    data: qs.stringify({ email, password }),
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8"
    }
  })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);

      //the accestoken is set as a cookie in order to check routes
      Cookies.set("accesstoken", res.data.accesstoken);
      //we have to check the accesstoken manually before redirecting it to login, or else it will allow navigate since its not a <PrivateRoute> component
      isAuthenticated().then(result => {
        if (result === true) {
          this.setState(
            { isAuthenticated: true, authenticationChecked: true },
            () => {
              this.props.history.push("/");
            }
          );
        } else {
          this.setState({
            isAuthenticated: false,
            authenticationChecked: true
          });
          if (res.data == "Password not correct") {
            console.log("me va a hacer un return del pass");
            return "Password not correct";
          } else if (res.data == "User doesnt exist") {
            return "User doesnt exist";
          }
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

Which I pass to one of my routes as a prop

```
<Route exact path="/login" render={(props) => <LoginPage login={this.login} {...props} />} />
```

Altho the function works, it always evaluates to undefined because it's not awaiting the return

```js
handleSubmit(event) {
  const { email, password } = this.state;
  var loginStatus = this.props.login(email, password);
  console.log("estado del login");
  console.log(loginStatus); //this always evaluates to undefined, even if the return happens
  if (loginStatus == "Password not correct") {
    this.setState({
      wrongPassword: true
    });
  } else if (loginStatus == "User doesnt exist") {
    this.setState({
      wrongUser: true
    });
  }
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

But since its a function passed as a prop, I don't really understand how to implement an await there, I have tried  setting the login function as async and then awaiting the prop like this

```
const loginStatus =  await this.props.login(email, password)
```

But React won't let me do that

Comment: did you marked your function as async?

Comment: this.props.login isn't returning a promise so no use in using await on it

Comment: you need to return the axios call

Comment: what error does react throwing?

Comment: @GauravBhusare ```Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function``` That is in react, if i set ```const loginStatus =  await this.props.login(email, password)```

Comment: you need to mark the function as async

Comment: @GauravBhusare and how am I supposed to do that in a prop function? Thats my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to create a promise

```
 app.js   
      login = (email, password) => {
            return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
                axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: 'http://localhost:3003/login',
                    data: qs.stringify({ email, password }),
                    headers: {
                        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
                    }
                }).then((res) => {
                    console.log(res)

                    //the accestoken is set as a cookie in order to check routes
                    Cookies.set('accesstoken', res.data.accesstoken);
                    //we have to check the accesstoken manually before redirecting it to login, or else it will allow navigate since its not a <PrivateRoute> component
                    isAuthenticated().then((result) => {

                        if (result === true) {
                            this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true, authenticationChecked: true }, () => {
                                this.props.history.push('/');
                            })
                            resolve(true);
                        } else {
                            this.setState({ isAuthenticated: false, authenticationChecked: true })
                            if (res.data == "Password not correct") {
                                console.log("me va a hacer un return del pass")
                                reject("Password not correct");
                            } else if (res.data == "User doesnt exist") {

                                reject("User doesnt exist")
                            }
                        }
                    });


                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
            })

        }
```

handleSumbit

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    this.props.login(email, password).
        then((data) => {
            console.log("entrada");
            console.log(data)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)

            if (err == "Password not correct") {
                this.setState({
                    wrongPassword: true
                })
            } else if (err == "User doesnt exist") {
                this.setState({
                    wrongUser: true
                })
            }
        })

    event.preventDefault();


}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
async handleSubmit(event) {
     const { email, password } = this.state;
     var loginStatus = await this.props.login(email, password)
     console.log("estado del login")
     console.log(loginStatus); //this always evaluates to undefined, even if the return happens
    if (loginStatus == "Password not correct"){
         this.setState({
            wrongPassword : true
        })
    }else if(loginStatus == "User doesnt exist"){
        this.setState({
            wrongUser : true
        })
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Your function should be like this

Comment: that still returns undefined

Comment: you should return something from if(result===true) condition